# "cannot load such file -- watir (LoadError)" when running Feature in Cucumber

Tags: automation, rubygems, cucumber, bundler, watir

I am currently setting up some Cucumber tests and my Hook file contains the following :

```
require 'watir'

Before do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
end

After do
  @browser.close
end
```

When I run my feature file I get the following:

```
cannot load such file -- watir (LoadError)
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/marklane/RubymineProjects/test_puppies/features/support/hooks.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/marklane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/cucumber:23:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

My Gem File Lock is:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    backports (3.10.3)
    builder (3.2.3)
    childprocess (0.8.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    cucumber (3.0.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      cucumber-core (~> 3.0.0)
      cucumber-expressions (~> 4.0.3)
      cucumber-wire (~> 0.0.1)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.3)
      gherkin (~> 4.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
      multi_test (>= 0.1.2)
    cucumber-core (3.0.0)
      backports (>= 3.8.0)
      cucumber-tag_expressions (>= 1.0.1)
      gherkin (>= 4.1.3)
    cucumber-expressions (4.0.4)
    cucumber-tag_expressions (1.0.1)
    cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
    data_magic (1.2)
      faker (>= 1.1.2)
      yml_reader (>= 0.6)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    faker (1.8.4)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.9.18)
    gherkin (4.1.3)
    i18n (0.9.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    multi_json (1.12.2)
    multi_test (0.1.2)
    page-object (2.2.4)
      page_navigation (>= 0.10)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 3.0)
      watir (~> 6.8)
    page_navigation (0.10)
      data_magic (>= 0.22)
    rake (12.2.1)
    rspec (3.7.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-core (3.7.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.7.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.7.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-support (3.7.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.1)
    selenium-webdriver (3.6.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
    watir (6.8.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 3.4, >= 3.4.1)
    yml_reader (0.7)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  cucumber
  data_magic
  page-object (~> 2.0)
  rake
  rspec
  watir
```

I am unsure why this error is occurring when I have Watir installed. When I require Watir and run the script just using the ruby file then it works ok. As soon as do the same using the Feature it errors.

When Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the output from `gem list` run at the command line.   If you have not run `bundle install` to install the required gems, even if they are in your gemfile, you may not have them on your system, which is the most common cause of that error.  The gem list command will show us what gems have actually been installed on your system.

Comment: Also if you can show us what you have in your `env.rb` file that may be useful in troubleshooting this as well.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but does apply to where you are trying to start the browser when running cucumber.  Unless you want the overhead of starting up the browser for each scenario, I recommend starting up the browser in support/env.rb  Then in the before hook you can just do something like clearing cookies to get the equivalent of a fresh browser for each scenario.

Otherwise if you are opening the browser at the start of each scenario, and closing it at the end your features will be much slower to execute just due to the time it takes to spin up the browser session for every single scenario.